# What is the easies way to set a password for an AWS Cognito user?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In the AWS Cognito console, you can only set a temporary password for a user and the user has to change their password on first login. Since we primarily use Facebook login, and direct user pool users only for special cases (e.g. admin scripting), we don't have the password login flow implemented at all.

Is there any publicly available (e.g. AWS hosted) page which could be used for setting the password of a user from any user pool?  Or is there a simple way of creating a page for ourselves?

I've found one way to do this through the AppSync console, but it's quite cumbersome (will write it in the answer for reference).

Answer (score 1):

The cumbersome way I've found using AppSync console is:

1. Open the [AppSync console](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/appsync/home) in the appropriate region
2. Create a new API with 'Build from scratch' option
3. Go to Settings and change the Default authorization mode to Amazon Cognito user pool, choose the appropriate user pool and Save
4. Go to Queries and choose Login with User Pools
5. Enter the user pool `cognito_app_clientWeb` App client ID, username and temporary password
6. You'll receive a prompt to change your password (where you can fill in the exact same temporary password)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found the following to be helpful:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/24

https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/change-cognito-user-force_change_passwore-to-confirmed/ (This is more helpful and you just need to follow the provided steps in order but the page is in Japanese, so use Google Translate)

The only way is to use AWS CLI. If you need to do this often, writing a script would be recommended.